# Can I convert a date in the format YYYYMMDDHHMM using date?

Tags: date

I have a date of the format YYYYMMDDHHMM. For example, `201607131001` would be `10:01 AM July 13, 2016`. Is there any way I can use the `date` utility to format the timestamp?

Comment: Format it to what?

Comment: Format it using the date formatting parameters. For example, perhaps in the format I gave as the example - `10:01 AM July 13, 2016`

Comment: `strptime` from [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) can help you parse any date / time format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU date, we need to add a space between the date and time and pass it with `-d`

```
$ date -d "20160713 1001"
Wed Jul 13 10:01:00 EDT 2016
```

We can do that split pretty easily with parameter expansions.  e.g

```
$ d=201607131001
$ date -d "${d%????} ${d#????????}"
Wed Jul 13 10:01:00 EDT 2016
```

You can then use the standard `+` formatting strings to get it in the format you want (`man date` explains all the options).

```
$ d=201607131001
$ date -d "${d%????} ${d#????????}" +"%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y"
10:01 AM July 13, 2016
```

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime -s t -r %Y%m%d%H%M 201607131001
LC_ALL=C strftime '%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y' $t
```

With busybox `date`:

```
date -D %Y%m%d%H%M -d 201607131001 +'%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y'
```

With AT&T ast-open `date`:

```
date -p %Y%m%d%H%M -d 201607131001 +'%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y'
```

With BSD `date`:

```
date -jf %Y%m%d%H%M +'%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y' 201607131001
```

With `ksh93`:

```
printf '%(%I:%M %p %B %d, %Y)T\n' 201607131001
```

Comment: To keep it going with PHP `echo date('h:i A F j, Y', strtotime('201607131001'));`